# .htaccess regex issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,3})\/([0-9])\.html$  thread.php?board=$1&thread=$2
```

Here is my .htaccess file. Let me explain you how it should work:

```
website.com/vg/1337.html => website.com/thread.php?board=vg&thread=1337
```

in the other words:

```
website.com/x/y.html => website.com/thread.php?board=x&thread=y
x - 1-3 symbols, A-z, 0-9;
y - unlimited amount of symbols, 0-9;
```

It does look pretty simple, but...
website.com/vg/1337.html just leads me to 404.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the error_log say regarding that request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regular expression only matches URLs that contain a single digit, for example "5.html".

To fix it change `[0-9]` to `[0-9]+`. The [plus](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) means "one or more of the previous token".

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]* or [0-9]+
```

missing enumerator after [0-9]. if you don't put anything, it would work for one char only

Answer (score 1):

`y` is not "unlimited" in your example above, just allow one single digit. Add a star `*` after it (or a `+` for "1 or more").